# Advanced SQL help required

Tags: mysql, sql

I have just started out with sql and am unable to figure out how to get the information I need in a single query!

**Here is the SQLFiddle.com:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/585dc/1

**Link to download of database file:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/16qvgj69ks385d8/sql.sql

The information I need from the query is the COUNT of the downloads, likes, views from their respective tables and the selection of all the information about the user from t_users plus the information about the note from t_notes and all of this must be gathered from just the userID. Basically I want all the information about all the notes that a single user has uploaded.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out with this because I have been trying to do it for hours!

This is as far as I could get:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t_notes.*, t_users.*
FROM t_notes, t_users 
WHERE t_users.userID = :userID
AND t_users.userID = t_notes.userID
GROUP BY noteID
ORDER BY noteUploadDate DESC
```

But then I did not know how to count all the amounts of downloads, likes and shares from the 3 different tables.

Comment: A couple of questions - 1) What SQL database engine are you writing for?  2) Do you want this query to return a single record per user?

Comment: @STLDeveloper I believe the OP is looking for data related to a specific user.

Comment: @Brandon - I guess I was confused by the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Brandon I am using MySQL and I would like it to return all the notes with the note information for certain user. Thanks

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to do advanced query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23442570/unable-to-do-advanced-query)

Answer (score 2):

Either of these queries will work (try both and see which one runs faster):

```
SELECT u.*,
       n.*,
       COUNT(DISTINCT d.downloadID) downloadCount,
       COUNT(DISTINCT l.likeID) likeCount
FROM t_users u
INNER JOIN t_notes n ON u.userID = n.userID
LEFT JOIN t_downloads d ON d.noteID = n.noteID
LEFT JOIN t_likes l ON l.noteID = n.noteID
WHERE u.userID = 1 -- write here the desired user id
GROUP BY n.noteID
```

```
SELECT u.*,
       n.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM t_downloads d 
          WHERE d.noteID = n.noteID) downloadCount,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM t_likes l
          WHERE l.noteID = n.noteID) likeCount
FROM t_users u
INNER JOIN t_notes n ON u.userID = n.userID
WHERE u.userID = 1 -- write here the desired user id
GROUP BY n.noteID;
```

Keep in mind however that you are retrieving all the info about the user (table `t_users`) as many times as notes exist for this user. On the other hand, you will not retrieve any record for a user that does not have notes. I don't know what your application logic is, but it seems to me that it would make more sense to retrieve the info in `t_users` in one query, and the info about notes (`t_notes`, download count, like count) in another query.

Comment: Good call, abl. It might be more portable to use LEFT OUTER JOIN unless the shortened version is actually part of the SQL standard.

Comment: @samitha Thank you so much! The only thing is that the amount of downloads and likes is always the same for each note and it is not the correct number. Any suggestions? Thanks! EDIT: It seems as if it is adding the downloads and likes count together.

Comment: @rpbodley You are right, the query was not correct. I have edited the answer.